# Country name pattern

Tags: pattern

Here are some specific country names:

> 1  Peru  or  Cuba
>
> 2  Mali or Angola
>
> 3  Laos
>
> 4  Oman or Nepal
>
> 5  ____

Please fill in the blank that will give you a country name that fits the pattern and explain the pattern. There are 2 possible answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blank can be filled with:

> **SPAIN** or **ISRAEL**

Why? Because the numbers indicate...

> ...the number of **English anagrams** that exist for these names!

As follows:

> PERU = PURE (1);
>  CUBA = [UBAC](https://encyclopedia2.thefreedictionary.com/ubac) (1);
>
>  MALI = LIMA, MAIL (2);
>  ANGOLA = [AGONAL](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/agonal), ANALOG (2);
>
>  LAOS = ALSO, [LOAS](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/Loas), [SOLA](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/solum) (3);
>
>  OMAN = [MANO](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mano), MOAN, [MONA](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/mona), [NOMA](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/noma) (4);
>  NEPAL = PANEL, PENAL, PLANE, [PLENA](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/plenum) (4);
>
>  and
>
>  SPAIN = [NIPAS](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/nipa), PAINS, [PIANS](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pian), [PINAS](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/pina), [SPINA](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sPina) (5);
>  ISRAEL = [ARIELS](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/ariel), [RESAIL](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/resail), [SAILER](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/sailer), [SERAIL](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/serail), SERIAL (5).
>
>  Some of these are obscure, but all anagrams can be double-checked on a site like [thewordfinder.com](https://www.thewordfinder.com/anagram-solver/).

Comment: I believe there exists some other logic here. Not saying this isn't correct but it seems that this might not be intended solution for some reason.

Comment: @I'mNobody If you have another answer with logic that fits, feel free to post it! :)

Comment: Lexico also has rot13(erynvf).